# Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks. Unit test with mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mocha.js, chai

While establishing the connection using socket

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done(
>   )" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Given below is the code reference of the same

```
beforeEach(function(done) {    
    var socketOptions = {};
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000", socketOptions);
    socket.on('connect', function () {
         console.log('Connection Established');
         setTimeout(done, 500);
    });
    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Connection Error', err);
        setTimeout(done, 500);
    });
});
```

While checking the error of socket connection, I'm getting the error mentioned below:

```
Connection Error { Error: xhr poll error
at XHR.Transport.onError (F:\Projects\SDK\dynamicLocationServer\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transport.js:64:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\SDK\dynamicLocationServer\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:129:10)
at Request.Emitter.emit (F:\Projects\SDK\dynamicLocationServer\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:133:20)
at Request.onError (F:\Projects\SDK\dynamicLocationServer\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:307:8)
at Timeout._onTimeout (F:\Projects\SDK\dynamicLocationServer\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:254:18)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5) type: 'TransportError', description:400}
```

Comment: `done` is not defined you might need to specify it as argument `beforeEach(function(done)`

Comment: I've specified it, but still getting the same error. If I call the `done` outside the socket connect, then it will work. Even if the connection fails, the test case will be resulting as passed.

Comment: Are you sure this line logs `console.log('Connection Established');`?

Comment: No, it is not getting logged even if server is up and running

Comment: Issue is resolved by changing the socketOptions variable data like `var socketOptions = {'transports': ['websocket']};`. Thanks for the help @YuryTarabanko

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved by changing the socketOptions variable data like

```
var socketOptions = {'transports': ['websocket']};
```

Since the error is on transport error polling, we need to specify the way of transports as options as pass with the socket connection options