# Unit test error with mocha: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded

Tags: mocha.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ganache

I'm getting a timeout error when I try to send the contract to Ganache. My code is as follows,

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const {interface,bytecode} = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async() => {
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
  .deploy({data: bytecode,arguments:['Hi There !'] })
  .send({from: accounts[0], gas:'1000000'});
});

describe("inbox", () => {
it('deploys a contract', () => {
    console.log(inbox);
 })
})
```

When I comment out the send method (provided below), the program runs without any issues. However, adding it back introduces the timeout error. No matter howmuch time I assign for mocha timeout, I still get the same error.

> .send({from: accounts[0], gas:'1000000'});

There are similar posts regarding timeout such as listed below,
[Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks. Unit test with mocha and chai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451140/error-timeout-of-2000ms-exceeded-for-async-tests-and-hooks-unit-test-with-moc)

[Unit test error with mocha and chai Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417229/unit-test-error-with-mocha-and-chai-timeout-of-2000ms-exceeded-for-async-tests)

[Mocha testing with promises: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819858/mocha-testing-with-promises-error-timeout-of-2000ms-exceeded)

[Mocha exceeding 2000ms timeout when returning a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069528/mocha-exceeding-2000ms-timeout-when-returning-a-promise)

None of the above solutions worked for me (mostly talking about increasing the timeout). Additionally, I downgraded web3 library as proposed in a different forum. However, it didn't work either.

You can find the exact issue posted by someone else at [a different forum](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2868). Apparently, that question has not received any potential answers as well.

Comment: try removing the gas property and check

Comment: @SanjaySB It returns an error when the gas limit is removed (the error: base fee exceeds gas limit).

Comment: what are the solc, web3 versions

Comment: @SanjaySB solc: 0.4.26 and web3: 1.0.0-beta.55. However, as mentioned in the post, I downgraded the versions and recompiled. None of them worked.

Comment: did you try the solc version 0.4.25?

Comment: @SanjaySB Yes. But, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed truffle v5.0.24 and started working on the truffle console which solved all the issues.